# How can I use a React component within a Node script?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I'm currently trying to use [react-pdf](https://github.com/diegomura/react-pdf) to generate and save a pdf to disk. Rendering to a webpage works, but the method that I need to invoke to save a pdf to disc,

```
    ReactPDF.render()
```

does not work within the npm start (react-scripts) way of running React that I've used in the past to create webpages. From reading [this issue](https://github.com/diegomura/react-pdf/issues/341), it seems that it needs to be run as a "Node only api". So my question is, what dependencies, commands, and steps do I need to take to run some react code and save a pdf to disk with something like

```
   > node index.js
```

currently when I run the above command I get

```
import React from 'react';
       ^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

Then, running

```
    node --experimental-modules index.mjs
```

I get

```
ReactPDF.render(<App />, `${__dirname}/output/test.pdf`);
                ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

Here are my two files:

index.js

```
    import React from 'react';
    import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
    import './index.css';
    import App from './App';
    import ReactPDF from '@react-pdf/renderer';


    ReactPDF.render(<App />, `${__dirname}/output/test.pdf`);
    //ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Document, Page, Text, View, StyleSheet } from '@react-pdf/renderer'

class App extends Component {



  render() {

    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
      page: {
        flexDirection: 'row',
        backgroundColor: '#E4E4E4'
      },
      section: {
        margin: 10,
        padding: 10,
        flexGrow: 1
      }
    });


    return (
      <Document>
        <Page size="A4" style={styles.page}>
          <View style={styles.section}>
            <Text>Section #1</Text>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.section}>
            <Text>Section #2</Text>
          </View>
        </Page>
      </Document>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "ccv-generator-react",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-pdf/renderer": "^1.4.2",
    "react": "^16.8.5",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.5",
    "react-scripts": "2.1.8",
    "ts-pnp": "^1.0.1",
    "typescript": "^3.3.4000"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ],
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1"
  }
}
```

A follow up question would be, Is what I am trying to do an anti-pattern?

Comment: How do I execute in a node only environment? When I try to run > node index.js it throws many errors. Whats the best way to setup the kind of environment I need?

Comment: `it throws many errors.`  It might help if you tell us..

Comment: I updated the question with more detail.

Comment: Because React’s component hierarchies and JSX integration make it excellent for creating PDFs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're running `index.mjs` directly from node, it does not go through the build and transpilation process of `react-scripts`, meaning you have to do it manually.

Node cannot directly parse jsx (`<App/>`, for example) - so you will need to run your code through [Babel](https://babeljs.io/setup#installation) with [React preset](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-react) in order to run it.

Since the dependecies should be already installed, try running:

```
npx babel index.mjs -o index-compiled.js --presets=es2015,react
```

and then run the compiled file:

```
node index-compiled.js
```

Comment: a step in the right direction, but it throws a syntax error when it tries to import ./index.css

Comment: @BijanMassoumi do you actually need `index.css`? It seems that the styling should be done only using their `StyleSheet` module

Comment: I could style through React. Wondering what this manual process is missing that the react-scripts do, considering it parses css just fine normally.

Comment: @BijanMassoumi  react-scripts uses webpack to compile, for things like CSS it uses something called loaders.   Having CSS loaded in a node.js app doesn't make any sense.  The `StyleSheet.create` I assume won't be css, but a subset that react-pdf can parse and generate your pdf from.  You can even use webpack to compile for node.js, but this wouldn't help anyway, as again CSS in node has no meaning.